# JSON-LD frame for mixed type definitions: @type and rdf:type in the same graph

Tags: json-ld

Sometimes constructing graphs using sparql creates JSON-LD documents that have mixed type definitions instead of @type (both rdf:type and @type in same graph). See this [gist](http://json-ld.org/playground/#/gist/395b51f75c4bccb24748) in JSON-LD Playground.

Example graph with mixed type definitions:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "label": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label",
    "ex": "http://example.org/ex#",
    "rdf": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
    "rdfs": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
  },
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "ex:Test1",
      "rdf:type": "ex:ExampleClass",
      "label": "Test 1"
    },
    {
      "@id": "ex:Test2",
      "@type": "ex:AnotherExampleClass",
      "label": "Test 2"
    }
  ] 
}
```

Is there a way to use frame to transform all the instances to use @type instead of rdf:type?

Comment: This problem was related to bad identifiers. Some of the identifiers were strings instead of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you have bad data like rdf:type pointing to strings. Didnt find a way to fix this with frame but fixing the data works.